# java: Null character replacing every 32768 char when reading from InputStream

Tags: java, null, inputstream, bufferedreader

I'm trying to read a CSV file from an InputStream (which orginates from a Mule SFTPInputStream). It works perfectly for small files. However, if it's reading a large file, every 32768th character is replaced by a null character '\0'.

This messes up my application. Why does that happen?

```
BufferedReader br = null;
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));

char[] chars = new char[4*1024];
int len;
while((len = br.read(chars))>=0) {
    stringBuilder.append(chars, 0, len);
}
String fileContents = stringBuilder.toString().trim();
```

UPDATE:

I uploaded the file to my server. I checked if there are any null characters in the file but there weren't any. Then, I uploaded the file to a SFTP using the bash sftp command. The file is then read from the SFTP server automatically through Mule and when I check the logs, I can see that the null character is there.

Could it be that null characters are added when I transfer the file to the SFTP through the sftp bash command?

Comment: How certain are you that the file is written correctly in the first place?

Comment: Do a hex dump on the file to verify it doesn't already contains the null character

Comment: you could always write code to handle that situation

Comment: Jon: Somewhat certain. I have checked in notepad++ with "show all characters" enabled. In the original file there is no null characters.. but in the post-processed file there is. 

Steve: I did a hex dump on but how do I know if it contains null? What should I search for in the hex dump? 

Dazedy: True. That will be my last resort.